# impossible to load the 2019 hansen GLAD alerts in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I had a functionnal process that was displaying glad alerts. both for 2019 and 2020.
Since yesterday it doesn't work anymore.

I was using the following code :

```js
var all_alerts  = ee.ImageCollection('projects/glad/alert/UpdResult')
var country     = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'SN'));

var alerts_2020 = all_alerts.select('conf20').mosaic().clip(country);
var alertMasked = alerts_2020.mask(alerts_2020.gt(0));
Map.addLayer(alertMasked, {palette:['red']}, 'alert');
```

it still work for 2020 but if you select the `conf2019` band, it will raise the following error :

> Tile error: Error in map(ID=08_04_ASIA):
> Image.select: Pattern 'conf19' did not match any bands.

I try to verify this problem by running :

```js
var alert_year = all_alerts.select('conf19').first().clip(country); //lucky me it's on Singapore
var alert_masked = alert_year.mask(alert_year.gt(0));
Map.addLayer(alert_masked, {palette:['green']}, 'alert_2019');
```

And there I can see my alerts. If you reverse `conf19` and `conf20` in my two proposed codes, you'll get two errors. Does anyone see what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every august they remove the last year band from the project (when I asked this question it was 2019). If you still want to use other years alerts you can find them under the following project in earthengine :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/glad/alert/2019final

You can then change the year from 2017 to now

Comment: The 2020 band has now gone too. Generally it is better to use the annual Hansen Forest Change layers as a base line than looking at GLAD alerts that are older than the annual layer. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UMD_hansen_global_forest_change_2021_v1_9?hl=en

Comment: for sure but sometime it's also useful for reporting and check the level of agreement between what was done on the field and what was analysed using EO